# WebM video format - Browsers compatibility

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, html5-video, webm

How are you doing?

Well. I'm running 3 videos on my website - HTML5

- 1st video > Specs: 4K 3840 × 2160 pixels - .WebM format
- 2nd video > Specs: FullHD 1080p 1920 x 1080 pixels - .WebM format
- 3rd video > Specs: FullHD 1080p 1920 x 1080 pixels - .mp4 format

As known **.webm** has compatibility pratically with all browsers.

I made a really simple **test** to **check which browser** has **compatibility with .webm**

**Selected browsers for the test I've done:**

- Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge.

**1st test**:

- **Browsers** that **definitely have compatibility with .webm** after playing the video on my website:

  Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge. (Definitely, Safari is the only not acceptable)

**2nd test:**

**Browsers** that definitely **worked** on **4K .WebM**:

- Google Chrome, Opera and Microsoft Edge.

**3rd test:**

**Browsers** that definitely **worked** on **1080p .WebM**:

- Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge.

**4th test:**

**Browsers** that definitely **worked** on **1080p .mp4**:

- Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge.

**Conclusion:** From the list (Google Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge) all browsers can play **.webm format**, except safari.

- From the list of browsers that can play **.webm** (Google Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Microsoft Edge), all of them can run 4K. Only Firefox doesn't **accept 4K .webm** (firefox only accepts 1080p .webm)
- Safari definitely can't run **.webm format.**

If you wanna check the tests I've done by yourself, please access my website link: http://167.71.100.135

**Here is the point:**

- I'm definitely fine that **Safari** **doesn't work** with **.webm**
- **What I really don't "accept" is the way Firefox goes.** Does anyone
  knows why Firefox can't run on **4K .webm**? As mentioned before, maximum
  resolution I could get on firefox was **1080p .webm**

Does anyone know how to make it works on **4K .webm**? I'm really not satisfied with maximum firefox **1080p .webm**, knowing that all others browsers do the 4K job.

Thank you very much!

I value your feedback, so let me know what you think!

Sincerely,
Mat

Answer (score 1):

How are you my friend?

Yes, the video 4k is 3.8GB, 2k is 1.5GB and 1080p 800MB.

Exactly, the videos are an hour long and I can play smoothly the 4K video using any browser (chrome, opera and microsoft edge). I can't play only on firefox. (Firefox only accepts only max 1080p)

Oh yeah, I tried with a shorter video for sure. It's a 5min 4k (600mb) video and firefox doesn't accept... here is the link, you can try by yourself, please: http://167.71.100.135/5min-4k-600mb

Look forward to hearing from you.

Sincerely,
Mat

Answer (score 0):

Do these videos play if you just open them locally in the browser?  The videos are an hour long, and the 4k video is 3.8 GB, the 2K is 1.5 GB and the 1080p is  800 MB.

Perhaps trying with a shorter video? I am able to play a 600MB 4k video in Firefox opening from localhost.

Have you thought about streaming a video of this size?

EDIT:
Looking at the 3 videos with FFprobe, the 4k and 2k videos are VP9 encoded, and the 1080p is h264 encoded.  You should standardise the encoding on all 3 videos, to ensure that it really is the size, and not the encodings:

https://www.streamclarity.com/probe?url=http://167.71.100.135/wp-content/uploads/media/webm1080p.webm

Comment: How are you my friend?

Yes, the video 4k is 3.8GB, 2k is 1.5GB and 1080p 800MB.

Exactly, the videos are an hour long and I can play smoothly the 4K video using any browser (chrome, opera and microsoft edge). I can't play only on firefox. (Firefox only accepts only max 1080p)

Oh yeah, I tried with a shorter video for sure. It's a 5min 4k (600mb) video and firefox doesn't accept... here is the link, you can try by yourself, please: http://167.71.100.135/5min-4k-600mb

Look forward to hearing from you.

Sincerely,
Mat